# kivy file that will not change my buttons

Tags: android, python, kivy

I have a small but annoying problem with a .kv file. I want to style a specific button so I made a .kv file with the Word as root class.
In it the child mybutton. but it gives me:

```
 font_size: 30
          ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I do not see the error with this

when I would change the mybutton to button it works but then it would change all buttons. (there will be more than one).

the python code:

```
class Word(Widget):


 def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(Word, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    mybutton = Button(text='my button')

    mybutton.bind(on_press=self.callback)
    self.add_widget(mybutton)



class WordApp(App):

 def build(self):   
    Window.clearcolor = (0,0,0.3,1)
    return Word()



if __name__ == '__main__':
 WordApp().run()
```

the word.kv:

```
<Word>:

    mybutton:
        font_size: 30  
        width: root.width
```

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how the `.kv` file works. The `<Word>:` entry provides a rule for how to build `Word` objects. If you change `mybutton:` to `Button:` in your `.kv` file, then your call to `Word()` in `build()` will create a `Word` instance with a button already in it (and that button will have the desired `font_size`). It will not affect other `Button` instances.

Comment: ok thank you that makes sense. Can you give me an example of how to style mybutton ? because thats were I get the syntax error

Comment: @ikolim has provided an excellent example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example demonstrates how to style mybutton in kv file.

## Example

### word.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

<Word>:
    Button:
        id: mybutton
        text: 'my button'
        font_size: 30
        width: root.width
        on_press: root.callback(self)
```

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window


class Word(Widget):

    def callback(self, instance):
        print("\ncallback: instance.text=", instance.text)


class WordApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (0, 0, 0.3, 1)
        return Word()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    WordApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01]